# Android-Clicking a Rotated ListView gives wrong coordinates

Tags: android, animation

I have a ListView that can have one or more clickable items. When I apply a rotate animation the coordinates that are clicked correspond to the original position of the ListView items. For example a list with one item in portrait mode rotated 180 degrees will have the item upside down on the bottom of the screen, but the item gets the click event when I click the top of the screen. 180 degrees is just an example I want to be able to move an arbitrary angle. 
I've looked through all the listView properties but none seem to have any effect on the clickable coordinates. I would assume willChangeTransformationMatrix would do the trick but it doesn't, neither does invalidate or invalidateViews. Is there a property I'm overlooking or how would I go about moving the coordinates to the right place?

Thanks

sample code- list items highlight correctly when clicked, rotate with dpad_center, after rotated items highlight when original position is clicked. I've tried animating the animation, animationSet, and layoutAnimationController all same result.

```
public class ToDoList extends Activity {
    ListView myListView;
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final ListView myListView = new ListView(this);

    final ArrayList<String> todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    todoItems.add(0, "asdf");
    todoItems.add(0, "1234");

    // Create the array adapter to bind the array to the listview
    final ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
    aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,todoItems);

    // Bind the array adapter to the listview.
    myListView.setAdapter(aa);
    setContentView(myListView);
    myListView.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
          if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER)
            {
              aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
              //myEditText.setText("");
              RotateAnimation  ranim = new RotateAnimation(0f, 180f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
              ranim.setDuration(1000);  
              ranim.setFillAfter(true);
              ranim.willChangeBounds();
              ranim.willChangeTransformationMatrix();
              ranim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
              myListView.startAnimation(ranim);
              AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
              set.addAnimation(ranim);
              set.willChangeTransformationMatrix();
              set.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
              //set.setFillAfter(true);
              //set.setFillEnabled(true);
              LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(set, 0.5f);
              controller.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
              myListView.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
              return true;
            }
          return false;
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the correct coordinates. RotateAnimation affects only the rendering of a View, not its layout or touch events.

Comment: I guess when I asked "how would I go about moving the coordinates to the right place?" by "right" I meant the newly rotated place where pretty much any person would expect them to be (under the item that is actually clicked). Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: @JA1: Step #1 is for you to determine how to have a sideways `ListView`, without any animations. If you cannot do it without an animation, you cannot do it with an animation, either. Since I am not aware of a way you can have a sideways `ListView`, I suspect that you will need to revise your UI plans.

Comment: This is pretty disappointing, I had looked at other ways of rotating w/out animation but only found how to do it to ImageViews. I also just tried animating an imageView, moving across screen onTouch, and the coordinates don't follow it either, you have to re-touch the original position to re-animate. This seems like a huge limitation, but I still think I'm overlooking something simple or there could be some way to adjust the coordinates. I mean a ListView with >10 items that is scrolled through does do some adjustments for position when items scroll out of view, similar to animation

Answer (score 1):

starting with honeycomb , you could use a new animation API that allows you to do both animation and real movement (or rotation, or scaling,...) of views .

for older versions of android , animation only changes how the views are shown.